# Which intervention improves the ability to remember names the most?

Tags: memory, reference-request, educational-psychology

Is there research about psychological interventions to help the average person remember names? If so, which intervention or interventions have the best evidence base to support them?

Are there good academic books about the subject of how humans manage to remember names?

Answer (score 2):

*Too long for a comment, so given as answer.*

I know of no studies, but what teachers do is connect each name to a face (that is "elaborate") and repeat this elaboration each time they enter class and check attendance (sort of like learning vocabulary or a poem). Personally, I write down the names in the sitting order of the pupils or students, because I remember where which "face" sat. Another option is to find the person on Facebook, download a photo from their profile, and add that to a list of the names. Then I repeatedly look at that list. What also helps is actually addressing the person by name each time you speak to them, especially after they gave their name to you the first time, but also when you meet them again.

Hope this helps in case you want practical proven advice.